# Expo audio object unhandled promise rejection, soundObject is undefined - can't access object outside function where it was created

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a sound play when props.sound==true, and to stop when props.sound=false. I keep getting unhandled promise rejection errors and error undefined object.
Here is my code:

```
constructor(props)
    {super(props);
      this.soundObject = new Expo.Audio.Sound();
    }

  stopSound = async () => {
    await this.soundObject.stopAsync();
  }
  playSound = async () => {
    try{
      await this.soundObject.playAsync();
    }catch(error){
      this.createSound()
      await this.soundObject.playAsync();
    }
    }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.createSound();
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.stopSound();
  }


  createSound = async() => {
    try {
      await this.soundObject.loadAsync(require('soundpath'));
      await this.soundObject.setVolumeAsync(0.3)
      await this.soundObject.setIsLoopingAsync(true)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("sound couldn't load")
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if (this.props.sound==true){
      this.playSound();
    } else {
      this.stopSound();
    }
  }
```

I've tried it using props, using state etc but it only works if i put playAsync in the original function i.e.

```
createSound = async() => {
    try {
      soundObject = new Expo.Audio.Sound();
      await soundObject.loadAsync(require('soundpath'));
      await soundObject.setVolumeAsync(0.3)
      await soundObject.setIsLoopingAsync(true)
      await soundObject.playAsync()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("sound couldn't load")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simple, use require('soundpath.mp3) //sound extension.

Comment: Now working, each time I have to call both loadAsync and playAsync (or stopAsync) but it is properly working - thank you!!